# Cannot access to_attr attribute in annotate()

Tags: python, django, prefetch, annotate

I have the following code:

```
queue = Queue_item.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('queue_item_id', 
queryset=Platform.objects.all().order_by('-time'), to_attr='platforms'))
queue = queue.annotate(first_time=Min('platforms__time')).order_by('first_time')
```

When I run it, I get an error message that says that in the queue.annotate, it cannot find platforms, even though I set it right before in the prefetch_related.

What am I missing?

[EDIT]

`#models.py`

```
import django
from django.db import models

class Queue_item(models.Model):
caption = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
path_to_picture = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def create(self):
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.caption.split(' ')[0]

class Platform(models.Model):

queue_item_id = models.ForeignKey(
    Queue_item,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)

time = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

INSTAGRAM = 'IG'
FACEBOOK = 'FB'
TWITTER = 'TW'

PLATFORM_CHOICES = (
    (INSTAGRAM, 'Instagram'),
    (FACEBOOK, 'Facebook'),
    (TWITTER, 'Twitter'),
)

platform = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=PLATFORM_CHOICES,
    default=INSTAGRAM
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: add your `Queue_item` model

Comment: models.py added!

Comment: try removing the `s` in `platforms__time`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reverse relation name is the default used by django: `platform` (the model name) , as it's shown here:

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    queue_item_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Queue_item,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

We could use the reverse name to execute queries, then you're trying to access it with `s` that is not correct.

```
...to_attr='platforms')...
queue.annotate(first_time=Min('platforms__time'))
```

The correct is:

```
....to_attr='platform')...
queue.annotate(first_time=Min('platform__time'))
```

OR

If you want to use `to_attr='platforms'` & `platforms__time` with `s`, you could change the *reverse name*:

```
queue_item_id = models.ForeignKey(
    Queue_item,reverse_name='platforms',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

> Since `queue_item_id` is a foreign key, no need to end the field name with `_id`. Just `queue_item` will be OK, Django has already create a similar for you like `queue_item_id`

Comment: Same issue for me: I have an event that has many missions, but I want to prefetch one specific type of mission and put it under a nice alias like "light_mission". So I Prefetch('mission_set', ..., to_attr='light_mission'). I then try to get values from my main queryset like: queryset.prefetch_related(..the prefetch expression).values('light_mission__status'): This fails as light_mission is unknown. Same with annotate. It is like the prefetch function doesn't add the to_attr value inside the known fields.